# Visual Studio Code in openSuse can't find Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, opensuse

Steps followed:

- Git is installed in `/usr/bin/git`, and
- I've changed the `git.path` variable to "`/usr/bin/git`"

However: Visual Studio Code still can't find Git and activate source control.

I'm running OpenSuse Leap, fully up to date as of today 29/12/18.

Comment: What are the steps you have followed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it. It was working as expected, just needed to initialise a repository in a project folder to get VS Code to recognise source control was working.

Answer (score 2):

The `git.path` setting should be:

```
/usr/bin/git
```

Not `/usr/bin.git`

Make sure `/usr/bin/git` is an *executable* file (not a folder)

Comment: Sorry, just made an edit, I mistyped that in the summary - I meant /usr/bin/git

Comment: I understand. Still, the rest of the answer applies.